# Preloadings images slowing page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preloading

I have a slideshow built in jquery which stores image urls in an array. When you click on the next button it sends a request to the server to get the image, then show it. This works but the image load progressively from top to bottom once they are retreived. I solved this by adding the following code...

```
//Preload background images
            function MM_preloadImages() { 
              var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
                var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
            }
            MM_preloadImages(<%= preloadImages %> );
```

The problem now is the the first image takes ages to load. I though the page would load with the first image then the others in the preload function in the background?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Wow, is it just me or did voting just get a whole lot more fun?

Comment: @quertymk: it's everyone.  A little April fools bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we can't tell what order the preload happens from the code you posted, but you could change your code to only run MM_preloadImages after the current page has finished loading.

That said, it looks like you are preloading all the images at the start.  Why not only preload the next image or two and keep doing that every time the slideshow advances?  This way the browser isn't still busy trying to load the entire show while the user is trying to go to the next slide.

Comment: Thanks. Since I have jquery loaded in the page I used $(window).load(function(){ and it works a treat.